# How to use several operators within tuple comparison

Tags: mysql, tuples, where-clause

I am using mysql and my table is as follows:

```
col_a: varchar(50)
col_b: varchar(50)
created_at: timestamp
```

I would like to do run the following query but by using tuples:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WEHRE col_a = x AND col_b = y AND NOW()-created_at >= z
```

I am aware of the following query but it only allows direct comparison (=) and not other operators (>=) which are required in the third argument:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE (col_a, col_b, col_c) IN <tuple_list_goes_here>
```

Can I use different operators with a `IN` query?

Comment: I am not clear what you want here. Please add sample data and desired outcome as text to help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

An `IN()` predicate only evaluates equality, not any other comparison operation.